# Spying or Identification tool IN RPA

Tags: rpa

Actually , what is going on background, when we are spying elements or identifying elements. I need some technical answers and difference between the modes available in BP????

Answer (score 0):

To get a better understanding of spying the elements try to observe the attributes. The element we spy is identified by its location (Path), size, value, type etc. in HTML, Win32, AA modes. but, this is completely different in Region mode. region mode just takes elements as part of a screen.